# remove value from after space detects

Tags: c#, asp.net

I just want to remove values from string after space

Example

if string value is (Music powerbanks pendrives) then it should replace it with (Music)

```
string productCategory = "Music PowerBank pendrives";
```

I just want to get first word from string

Comment: `productCategory = productCategory.Split(' ').First();` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int index = productCategory.IndexOf(' ');
if (index != -1)
    productCategory = productCategory.Substring(0, index);
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to get the first position (index) of a space character in your string. You can do that with the `IndexOf` function.
Then you need to check if `IndexOf` has found a space. To do so you have to check if the index return by `IndexOf` is higher than minus one. If it found an index you have to select all text from position 0 to the index of the first space. You can use the `SubString` function to select a specific amount of chars from a string. You have to pass the start-index (0) and the amount (length) of chars to select. Our length is the first index.

```
var index = yourstring.IndexOf(' '); //get the index of first space
string result;
// check if space exists
If (index > -1) {
    // if space exits, get the value from index 0 to the index of the space
    result = yourstring.SubString(0, index);
} else {
    // if no space exists then took the whole string as result 
    result = yourstring;
}
```